# How can i upload android apk to Fabrics without using plugin

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Is there a way to upload any working apk file to Fabrics?

I know how this works if you have the plugin and using Android Studio. But i am currently developing with React Native and an there is no plugin for WebStorm.

#### Update

Thanks Mike for the fast answer. According to your post i tried to run with the gradle version. It didn´t work running with

```
gradle assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

but instead it worked when i ran with

```
./gradlew assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

The problem now is that i am getting some errors which i don´t know how to handle with:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease'.
> Distribution upload failed.

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Distribution upload failed.
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:329)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.this$2$callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder$_crashlyticsUploadDistribution_closure16.doCall(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:249)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:558)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:539)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator$1.execute(TaskMutator.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator$1.execute(TaskMutator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.PluginException: Distribution upload failed.
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:666)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgsInternal(DeveloperTools.java:348)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.gradleMain(DeveloperTools.java:292)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:313)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.DistributionException: Crashlytics halted compilation because it can't distribute the unsigned APK: /Users/Adel/Socialbit/React/exampleApp/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DistributionTasks.uploadDistribution(DistributionTasks.java:57)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:664)
    ... 60 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 5.857 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: The issue is towards the bottom of the stacktrace. You're trying to distribute an unsigned APK. 

Crashlytics halted compilation because it can't distribute the unsigned APK: /Users/Adel/Socialbit/React/exampleApp/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk

We required the SDK to be signed to be distribued through Beta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here. Yes, there are many ways to upload the APKs and you can use any of the following commands.

If you're using Ant, [reference doc](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/ant.html):

```
ant release crashlytics-upload-distribution
```

If you're using Gradle, [reference doc](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html):

```
gradle assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

If you're using Maven, [reference doc](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/maven.html):

```
mvn install com.crashlytics:crashlytics-maven:UploadDistribution
```